# Using Laravel with external API instead of database

Tags: php, api, laravel-4

I've been trying to make a mobile app which uses an API to fetch resources. So far, so good. Now I need to make the website and I want to use the same API.

The API is built on the top of Slimframework and illuminate/database. So I'm wondering is it good to use Laravel for something that has no connection to the database directly?

For example, components such as Auth will require to supply a different driver and etc.

Would you recommend using Laravel 4.2 for this kind of purpose? What kind of advice can you give me?

Answer (score 0):

It's time to switch now laravel 5.0. I would recommend you to use Laravel for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is ok, try using Laravel 5 instead 4.2